# Github and Drupal

Tags: web, github, drupal-7, hosting

Pardon me if this question is not a good fit but i am unable to find relevant material. I have searched across the net and have found many answers but i still want to ask the question.

I am developing a Drupal 7.23 website. It will mostly use views. Not too heavy site. Now, can i host the site on github. We would be two people working on the project and so i thought of using Git. However i am unsure how to do this or if this can be done. hosting the drupal site, the db etc...Can you guide me on this or provide some links...i can carry it from there.

Apologies again if not the right place to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

[GitHub pages](http://pages.github.com/) could host only static pages, without any database backend.

And generally, GitHub is hosting service for software projects, which means it could help you store your code, but not for websites, because it will not run your code.